# ggvis plot with error bars - custom axis text

Tags: r, ggvis

I am trying to create a ggvis plot with error bars. I decided to plot mean values as points and error bars as rectangles. Here is my data set:

```
mivector<-c(1.5,2,2.5,2,2.5,3,2.5,3,3.5)
treats<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")

library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

plotdf<-data.frame(mivector,treats)

plotdf<- plotdf %>% group_by(treats) %>% 
summarise(mimean=mean(mivector),misd=sd(mivector)) %>%
mutate(milow=mimean-misd,mihigh=mimean+misd,mileft=as.numeric(treats)-0.005,miright=as.numeric(treats)+0.005,treatsno=as.numeric(treats)) %>% 
select(-misd)
```

And here is the plotting code I am trying to make:

```
plotdf %>% ggvis() %>% layer_points(~treatsno,~mimean) %>%
layer_rects(prop("x",~mileft),prop("y",~milow),prop("x2",~miright),prop("y2",~mihigh),fillOpacity:=1) %>%
scale_numeric("y", domain = c(0, 5)) %>%
add_axis("y",grid=F) %>%
add_axis("x",ticks=length(plotdf$treats),grid=F,properties=axis_props(labels=list(text=c("a","b","c"))))
```

I got stuck at the point that I cannot assign labels to the axis ticks properly. Instead of having 3 ticks with the text "a", "b" and "c" correspondingly, I have "a,b,c" for every tick.

Could you please indicate what I am doing wrong? Maybe there is generally a much easier way to make error bars which I am not aware of?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would seem `ggvis` is not very flexible at mixing factors and numeric data. I get `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : Scales must all be countable, or all not countable.` when I try to convince `ggvis` that I would like to plot A, B and C on the x axis... None of the examples I've seen online or in the help files use categorical data on one axis.